# Iterating over Ansible debug output

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

The following is my task:

```
  - name: Get pods
    shell: kubectl -n kube-system get pods -o json | jq '.items[] | .metadata.name'
    register: result

  - debug:
    var=result2

  - debug:
    msg: name is {{result.stdout['name']}}
```

The output when I run the playbook is:

```
    ok: [tester] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": true,
        ...
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "{\"name\":\"nginx-79cdd9df6b-8xbpz\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\"}"
        "stdout_lines": [
            "{\"name\":\"nginx-79cdd9df6b-8xbpz\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\"}"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to parse the `stdout` and get the `name` of the output. However, the debug stage fails on using `result.stdout.name` or `result.stdout['name']` and gives the following error:

```
the error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to...
: line 25, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

How can I parse a JSON output from a debug variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your debug output, you can see that `result.stdout` is a *string*. The contents are a JSON-encoded dictionary.  If you want to access attributes of that dictionary directly, you will need to deserialize the JSON using the `from_json` filter, like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ (result.stdout|from_json).name }}"
```

Comment: thank you, this worked for me. I was trying with `to_json` to convert the output string to json but it was failing.

Comment: `from_json`, really powerful!

Comment: the same debug statement doesn't work when the stdout contains more than one value. example:  ```"stdout": "{\"name\":\"nginx-79cdd9df6b-8xbpz\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\"}"\n"{\"name\":\"nginx-19ce8df6a-7xcqt\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\"}"```

Comment: In that example, you would need to decode each line separately, probably by iterating over `stdout_lines`.